# Class Design (design patterns) ideas in java?

Tags: java, design-patterns

I am trying to learn design principles in java... where they say, program an interface and implement an interface rather than classes..

Keeping that in mind, here is my use case..

Read two formats of data (csv and json)from files..So, I am thinking of creating a "class" or module called "DataModel".. ?

And then an algorithm module where I have two algorithms at this point (Linear Regression and Logistic Regression)...

But, I can't get to think in "Design pattern" fashion.. If someone can help me what interfaces/patterns I should follow, it would be very helpful for me.

Just to give a context, I want to build a very simple machine learning library..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can implement [Strategy pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern) with different implementation for algorithm module.

The Strategy pattern is to be used where you want to choose the algorithm to use at runtime. In a standard library, [Comparator](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) is a good example of **Strategy** pattern. I take an example in [Effective Java](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321356683)

```
public interface Comparator<T> {
   public int Compare(T t1, T t2); 
}

public StringLengthsComparator implements Comparator<String> {
    public int.Compare(String s1, String s2) { return s1.length() - s2.length();}
}
```